# ASP.NET Core with form tag - validate form onsubmit and prevent submission

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, form-submit, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project where I use the form tag for a submission. Now I want to add some client side validation on my form submission. So I use the `onsubmit` tag on my form like this:

```html
<form id="formId" asp-action="ActionName" onsubmit="validationFunction(Event)">
```

and I have a function like this:

```js
function validationFunction(e) {
    //CheckStuff
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Now when I submit my form, the function is triggered properly but the `e.preventDefault()` doesn't stop the submission. Nor does `return false`.

How can I prevent my submission from completing?

PS. I know that I could probably handle the case with the button click and submit my form when I complete my validation but I was wondering why doesn't the above work in ASP.NET Core or what am I missing?

Comment: `asp-action` defines the controller action that the form should be submitted to, this has nothing to do with javascript functions.

Comment: @Jerodev You re right it was a mistake of me when I was writing the question. I corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onsubmit` attribute should be returned and `return false` to prevent the submitting.

```
<form id="formId" asp-action="ActionName" onsubmit="return validationFunction(Event)">
```

Comment: I don't know who is the guy that just came into the answer and downvoted everything but ok what can I say. Thanks for the answer it worked and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it "correct" and easiest way set the validation in the class ex:

```
public class Movie
{
public int ID { get; set; }

[StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
[Required]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Release Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

[Range(1, 100)]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }

[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
[Required]
[StringLength(30)]
public string Genre { get; set; }

[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
[StringLength(5)]
[Required]
public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation

Or with [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)
and even [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)

Comment: This would imply that the OP is using the validations provided by asp.net. OP is clearly writing his own functions

Comment: The answer's way can't be used in my case because I want to validate a lot of similar forms that have different endpoints but my model is one for the entire view. Thus I can't really set Data Annotation validation. The second way is a way that works and I know it but I was wondering why my way doesn't. It should work since I am stopping the event but I am missing something.